# Can the ANEW dictionary be used for sentiment analysis in quanteda?

Tags: r, nlp, sentiment-analysis, quanteda

I am trying to find a way to implement the Affective Norms for English Words (in dutch) for a longitudinal sentiment analysis with Quanteda. What I ultimately want to have is a "mean sentiment" per year in order to show any longitudinal trends.

In the data-set all words a scored on a 7-point Likert-scale by 64 coders on four categories, which provides a mean for each word. What I want to do is take one of the dimensions and use this to analyse changes in emotions over time. I realise that Quanteda has a function for implementing the LIWC-dictionary, but I would prefer using the open-source ANEW-data if possible.

Essentially, I need help with the implementation because I am new to coding and R

The ANEW file looks something like this (in .csv):

WORD/SCORE: cancer: 1.01, potato: 3.56, love: 6.56

Comment: Quanteda can use any dictionary of various formats. Surely you can do it. If you have some difficulties implementing it. You can ask with more details.

Comment: You are right, Quanteda can implement the following formats: LIWC, Yaml, Yoshikoder, Lexicoder and YAML, but ANEW is not one of them. Essentially, what I need help with is the implementation because I am new to R and coding.

Comment: If you point me a dictionary file and provide sample data, I can show a quick example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet, directly, but... ANEW differs from other dictionaries since it does not use a key: value pair format, but rather assigns a numerical score to each term.  This means you are not counting matches of values against a key, but rather selecting features and then scoring them using weighted counts.

This could be done in **quanteda** by:

1. Get ANEW features into a character vector.
2. Use `dfm(yourtext, select = ANEWfeatures)` to create a dfm with just the ANEW features.
3. Multiple each counted value by the valence of each ANEW value, recycled column-wise so that each feature count gets multiplied by its ANEW value.
4. Use `rowSums()` on the weighted matrix to get document-level valence scores.

or alternatively,

5. File an [issue](https://github.com/kbenoit/quanteda/issues) and we will add this functionality to **quanteda**.

Note also that **tidytext** uses ANEW for its sentiment scoring, if you want to convert your dfm into their object and use that approach (which is basically a version of what I've suggested above).

### Updated:

It turns out I already built the feature into **quanteda** that you need, and had simply not realised it!

This will work.  First, load in the ANEW dictionary. (You have to supply the ANEW file yourself.)

```
# read in the ANEW data
df_anew <- read.delim("ANEW2010All.txt", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# construct a vector of weights with the term as the name
vector_anew <- df_anew$ValMn
names(vector_anew) <- df_anew$Word
```

Now that we have a named vector of weights, we can apply that using `dfm_weight()`.  Below, I've first normalised the dfm by relative frequency, so that the document aggregate score is not dependent on the document length in tokens.  If you don't want that, just remove the line indicated below.

```
library("quanteda")
dfm_anew <- dfm(data_corpus_inaugural, select = df_anew$Word)

# weight by the ANEW weights
dfm_anew_weighted <- dfm_anew %>%
    dfm_weight(scheme = "prop") %>%   # remove if you don't want normalized scores
    dfm_weight(weights = vector_anew)
## Warning message:
## dfm_weight(): ignoring 1,427 unmatched weight features 

tail(dfm_anew_weighted)[, c("life", "day", "time")]
## Document-feature matrix of: 6 documents, 3 features (5.56% sparse).
## 6 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
##               features
## docs                 life        day       time
##   1997-Clinton 0.07393220 0.06772881 0.21600000
##   2001-Bush    0.10004587 0.06110092 0.09743119
##   2005-Bush    0.09380645 0.12890323 0.11990323
##   2009-Obama   0.06669725 0.10183486 0.09743119
##   2013-Obama   0.08047970 0          0.19594096
##   2017-Trump   0.06826291 0.12507042 0.04985915

# total scores
tail(rowSums(dfm_anew_weighted))
## 1997-Clinton    2001-Bush    2005-Bush   2009-Obama   2013-Obama   2017-Trump 
##     5.942169     6.071918     6.300318     5.827410     6.050216     6.223944
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I will try to hack away at the code to adres point 3. of you solution - hopefully it'll figure it out.

Comment: Firstly, thanks a lot for the support! 

I can run the code until the "weighting" where I get the following error: 

"Error: not-yet-implemented method for *(<dfmSparse>, <character>).
 ->>  Ask the package authors to implement the missing feature.
In addition: Warning message:
In dfm_weight(., weights = vector_anew) :"

This error message is then followed by all the words as one string: "ignoringaalaalmoesaandachtigaangenaamaanslagaanstootaantrekkelij" (I'm using ANEW in dutch)

When I view the vector with the words and the weights everything looks fine.

Comment: UPDATE! I changed the txt-file to excel and this time I ran the code with the same error, but this time the dfm_anew_weighted variable was created.

Comment: It's not an error message, just a warning, but I have made it friendlier in the code for the next version.  It's telling you that 1,427 features from the ANEW dictionary are not found in the dfm (and in v0.9.9.50, it pastes them all together in the warning...). Still produces the correct result.

If you want to stop this, just change the weights argument to `weights = vector_anew[names(vector_anew) %in% featnames(dfm_anew)]`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the useful help and quick reaction. I implemented the code that you suggested on the corpus that I am using for my analysis, and it works like a charm!